# MariaDB in docker said - Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql, docker, timeout, mysql-workbench

I start mariadb docker with a number of important options

```
--connect_timeout  43200 --max_allowed_packet 1073741824 --net_read_timeout 100 --innodb_buffer_pool_size 64M
```

Also I have increased timeout in my wokrbench

[image]

But after a lot of experiments I still received lost connection.

Below I place my SQL command produced error. It's a dump from another working mariadb server, but without docker.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `AspNetUsers`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `AspNetUsers` (
  `Id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
  `UserName` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `NormalizedUserName` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `NormalizedEmail` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `EmailConfirmed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `PasswordHash` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `SecurityStamp` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `ConcurrencyStamp` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `PhoneNumber` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `PhoneNumberConfirmed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `TwoFactorEnabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `LockoutEnd` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LockoutEnabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `AccessFailedCount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DiscordId` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `DiscordEnabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `DiscordServerId` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `IsGoogleAuthenticatorEnabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `GoogleAuthenticatorSecretKey` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `IPAddress` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `UserAgent` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `ResetDone` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `APIKey` char(36) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UserNameIndex` (`NormalizedUserName`),
  KEY `EmailIndex` (`NormalizedEmail`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

this is log of container

```
2020-12-04  1:49:02 0 [Note] mysqld: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
2020-12-04  1:49:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 67108864, chunk size = 67108864
2020-12-04  1:49:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-12-04  1:49:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2020-12-04  1:49:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-12-04  1:49:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-12-04  1:49:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-12-04  1:49:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-12-04  1:49:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.5.8 started; log sequence number 67060; transaction id 71
2020-12-04  1:49:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-12-04  1:49:02 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-12-04  1:49:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 201204  1:49:02
2020-12-04  1:49:02 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-12-04  1:49:02 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@f29788dfc1fd' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2020-12-04  1:49:02 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
2020-12-04  1:49:02 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2020-12-04  1:49:02 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.5.8-MariaDB-1:10.5.8+maria~focal'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2020-12-04  4:00:53 4 [Warning] Aborted connection 4 to db: 'YYYYYYY' user: 'root' host: 'XX.XX.XX.XX' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
```

Are anybody understanding what happens?

Comment: Can we see your docker files / docker-compose.yml? what is the exact error / lost connection message you get?

Comment: `innodb_buffer_pool_size 64M` too small. How much ram do you have. Start with 1G if possible. Show the log from the docker container.

Comment: @mikey, I can not start maria db by YML at all, only by command line, If I start by YML I always receive [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Can't open file' when trying to use aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control' [ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writabl  [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.

Comment: @danblack I start in docker. Whole this machine has 4GB RAB

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution to run SQL script in dockerizing mariadb server. I run the same script in command line in the same machine:

```
sudo docker exec -i mariadb-server2 sh -c 'exec mysql -uroot -p"xxxxxxxx"' < /home/wwwadmin/tst1.sql
```

Why this script not working remotely through docker network and by Workbench I still don't understand. Interesting that I need uploading a huge database with a lot of tables and data, but only a couple of script induce this error "Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query". 99,9% of sql script working without this error.